# Configure multiple postgresql database according to environment variables in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

I am trying to configure two postgresql databases to my application. One is for local/development environment and one for public/production environment, the latter one will be deployed on Heroku.

Here is the code that should export either `pool` variable that will connect to their database;

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });
const app = require("./index");

const Pool = require("pg").Pool;

const pool = new Pool({
  user: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  port: 5433,
});

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log(`App running....`);
});

module.exports = pool;
```

The first one is for the local and the second is for heroku connection. But I can't configure how to use the two same-named variables at the same time, that will work according to production or development.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an ENV variable something called ENVIRONMENT, and that variable could have two values either local or prod and in the code, you should choose either one configuration or another depending of what value the Environment variable has, I would write that logic in this way:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });
const app = require("./index");

const Pool = require("pg").Pool;

const pool = process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'local' ? new Pool({
  user: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  port: 5433,
}) : new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log(`App running....`);
});

module.exports = pool;
```